# How do I delete current word/line on Debian?

Tags: debian, shell, keyboard-shortcuts

In macOS, wherever I am in the OS, I can <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the current line and <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the current word. Is there a similar shortcut on Debian? If yes, can it be reconfigured to the above?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the terminal or with a text editor?

Comment: everywhere outside of the terminal, in macOS it's great because it works everywhere, even in this <textarea>

Comment: What window manager or desktop system are you using (KDE, XFCE, Gnome, something else)?

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding keyboard shortcuts in most Unices are:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>: delete current line from cursor to beginning
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>: delete current line from cursor to end
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>: delete current word

Note: these keyboard shortcuts even work in Mac OS X!